# Ubuntu 18.04 - how to get rid of notifications at top of graphical file browser after a file event (delete/copy/etc.)?

Tags: 18.04, notification

Generally I really like Ubuntu 18.04, but one "feature" that I'm not a fan of is the notifications at the top of the graphical file browser after an event pertaining to files (copy, delete, etc.), ex:

[image]

Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Somebody in the questions asked why I'd like to suppress these messages.  The reason is I find this distracting, and additionally it blocks the view of the files on the top row.  This is a substantial hindrance when I'm moving many files around.

Further, anybody who has used computers much is aware that Ctrl+Z will undo an operation, so this message is really not necessary or beneficial.

Comment: Please explain why you would want to - particularly when the option to undo an erroneous selection is provided

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Don't get that. Ctrl-z suspends an action, not reverse it in Linux.

Comment: I can verify that in Ubuntu 18.04, with standard configurations, after an unwanted file delete, Ctrl+Z restores the file.

Comment: @24601 Please explain why the OP needs to justify their motivation to you? I came here looking for an answer to the same question (albeit for 20.04).

Comment: @Lexible the OP updated their question to explain their reasons which was good enough for me 